# Finding PMF when Random variable is a function of other random variables

Tags: probability

A tapping device observes digital signals {+1, -1} with probability {0.4, 0.6} respectively in one direction and with probability {0.7, 0.3} in other direction. A random variable Z is defined by sum of two signals:

```
Z = S1 + S2
```

where S1 and S2 are two signals observed in two way communication. 
Find PMF of Z and expectation of Z.

My approach to this is :

```
PMF of RV(S1) is : 0.4            if s = 1
                   0.6            if s = -1
and similarly for S2
                   0.7            if s = 1
                   0.3            if s = -1




      P(X,Y) = 

             P(1,1) = 0.4 * 0.7 = 0.28
             P(1,-1) = 0.4 * 0.3 = 0.12
             P(-1,1) = 0.6 * 0.7 = 0.42
             P(-1,-1) = 0.6 * 0.3 = 0.18
```

Now that I have joint probabilities of X and Y, I'll add X and Y and check their corresponding joint probability

```
            X           |           Y        |       Z         | P(X)
            1                       1                2         | 0.28
            1           |           -1       |       0         | 0.12
            -1                       1               0           0.42
            -1          |           -1               -2          0.18
```

In order to calculate the expectation, multiplying Z with its corresponding probability and adding it all up.
Is this correct?

Comment: can you use mathjax

Comment: I don't understand where to use it